# How to keep two digits in float number (PHP)

Tags: php, scientific-notation

How to make number like `3.0000000054978E+38` to `3.00` in PHP?

Many thanks!

Comment: `round()` it http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Wait, isn't 3.0XE+38 an extremely large number?

Comment: You have not shared the criteria how to make `3.0000000054978E+38` to `3.00`. Normally that is done with multiplication/division.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `round` to solve this since it is a number in scientific notation.  You can, however, use `substr`:

```
$i = 3.0000000054978E+38;
$i = substr($i, 0, 2); // $i is now the string 3.00
echo( number_format($i+1,2) );  // Will output 4.00
```

Comment: Round does work for scientific notation. There's nothing wrong with round and floats.

Comment: `$i = 3.0000000054978E+38; echo( round( $i, 2) );` That outputs 3.0000000054978E+38 on Windows, not 3.00

Comment: @Watcher: Sure, because it does what it has been documented for. But it's obvious that TS is not asking for string manipulation, isn't it?

Comment: OP asked for output of 3.00, AFAIK that's the only way to do it

Comment: @watcher: Yes if you treat the input as a constant, yours ain't wrong, but [it's not the only way to do it, round works perfectly well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10397974/367456).

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for the small fraction of your number being outputted in a formatted fashion:

```
$number = 3.0000000054978E+38;
printf('%.2f', $number / 1E+38); # 3.00
```

Comment: I'm not really sure it's better in the eye of the TS, it's still undefined what Acubi is specifically looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`round`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), as in `round($floating_number, 2)`.

Comment: Just out of interest, what's the advantage of this over number_format(3.0023123121, 2);?

Comment: `number_format` enforces the decimal places; actually it might be better to use in this case :P

Comment: Worth putting in the answers then. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf()` always gives you the specified number of decimal points, if you require.

```
sprintf('%0.2f', 3.0000000);
```

Would display `3.00`, if you echo it.